# Use MacOS Mail Big Sur on external SSD with MacOS Mail Sierra on Mac HD?

Tags: macos, mail.app, big-sur

My 2015 iMac continues to run Sierra for the sake of some software, but I have recently installed Big Sur on an external SSD. I would like to use Big Sur’s Mail application, but I don’t want to have to import my existing Mail structure into the external boot drive.  How can I use Big Sur’s Mail application and save all mails onto the Mac HD in the existing folders under Sierra’s Mail?

Answer (score 2):

You should not try to do this! You would be in serious danger of losing all your Mail.

Mail is stored in the ~/Library/Mail folder. Each version of macOS changes the structure and content of this folder. So you can't have one common Mail folder used by both Sierra and Big Sur.

If you want to access Mail from both Sierra and Big Sur you must keep them separate and configure what you need on each system.

You already have Mail on Sierra, so it is a matter of creating Mail accounts on Big Sur. Mail will download all your mail from whatever mail service(s) you use.

Caveat: I am assuming that you mail services use the IMAP protocol. If any of the Mail accounts use the POP protocol, I would not do even the above unless you are happy that you can recover your mail in the event of a mishap.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could I ask for further clarification? My mail services do use IMAP. I'm looking for a way to store emails on the Mac HD rather than on the external SSD. And I do often have to access older emails. Would it be possible to import my old emails into the Big Sur Mail app, but then store the structure somewhere on the Mac HD? Or am I stuck keeping everything on the external SSD?

Comment: You're going to struggle - for one thing Big Sur sits on APFS, Sierra on HFS. I don't see that being trouble-free no matter how you try to work it.

Comment: As @Tetsujin says, want you want would be messy and potentially a disaster. Keep them separate.  Sorry we can't encourage you.

Comment: Thank you, everyone. I have taken your advice, and set up Mail with Big Sur on the external SSD, keeping Mail with Sierra on Macintosh HD.